# np.ceil in python doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy, rounding, ceil

I'm actually having some problems with "np.ceil" in python.

```
import numpy as np

x_start = 0
y_start = 0
x_end = 2
y_end = 1
x_step = 0.4
y_step = 0.3

x_segment = int(np.ceil((x_end-x_start)/x_step))
y_segment = int(np.ceil((y_end-y_start)/y_step))

print "N. x: " + str(x_segment)
print "N. y: " + str(y_segment)

matrix = np.zeros((y_segment, x_segment), dtype=int)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def frange(x, y, jump):
  while x < y:
    yield x
    x += jump
for y in frange(y_start, y_end, y_step):
    print "***"
    for x in frange(x_start, x_end, x_step):
        count = 0
        print "(" + str(x) + "; " + str(y) + ")   m[" + str(y_segment - int(np.ceil(y/y_step)) - 1) + "][" + str(int(np.ceil(x/x_step)))+"]" + " | x/x_step: " + str(x/x_step) + " | np.ceil(x/x_step): " + str(int(np.ceil(x/x_step)))
```

I should obtain something like:

```
...
***
(0; 0)   m[3][0] | x/x_step: 0.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 0
(0.4; 0)   m[3][1] | x/x_step: 1.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 1
(0.8; 0)   m[3][2] | x/x_step: 2.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 2
(1.2; 0)   m[3][3] | x/x_step: 3.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 3
(1.6; 0)   m[3][4] | x/x_step: 4.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 4
***
...
```

But the number "3" is replaced with "4".

```
***
(0; 0)   m[3][0] | x/x_step: 0.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 0
(0.4; 0)   m[3][1] | x/x_step: 1.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 1
(0.8; 0)   m[3][2] | x/x_step: 2.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 2
(1.2; 0)   m[3][4] | x/x_step: 3.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 4
(1.6; 0)   m[3][4] | x/x_step: 4.0 | np.ceil(x/x_step): 4
***
```

Do you know why? How can I fix my code? Thank you!

Comment: Would using np.rint fix this rather than np.ceil?

Comment: Yes, it works with rp.rint, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer: Float imprecision issue

**Long answer**:

`frange` seems to have some float precision issues. Look what happens when you go through your `frange`:

If you just print the raw floats:

```
>>> [x for x in frange(x_start, x_end, x_step)]
[0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2000000000000002, 1.6]
```

for some reason, `1.2` is not exactly `1.2`. When you do:

```
np.ceil(1.2000000000000002/x_step)
```

you get `4.0` (in other words, `np.ceil` works as it should).

What you *want* is essentially `np.ceil(1.2/x_step)`, which is equal to `3.0`

I would recommend using `np.round()` or something similar to round your `x` values before applying `np.ceil()`